# introduction to modal logic

Tags: logic, modal-logic

I am not entirely sure if we are allowed to ask such questions here but I was wondering if anyone could suggest me a real introductory level textbook on modal logic

Comment: E.Zalta, [Basic Concepts in Modal Logic](https://mally.stanford.edu/notes.pdf) and Garson, [Modal Logic for Philosophers](https://books.google.it/books?id=rFpbAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover).

Answer (score 1):

*Chellas, Brian F.*, Modal logic. An introduction, Cambridge etc.: Cambridge University Press. XII, 295 p. hbk: £ 17.50; pbk: £ 6.50 (1980). [ZBL0431.03009](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0431.03009).

This is a very carefully written book. It goes into the beautiful completeness theorems for S5, S4 etc. but it starts out just assuming you know some propositional logic.